# Is there an obligatory gathering on Shabat or the Moadim?

Tags: shabbat, mitzvah, commentaries

In Devarim it is commanded to gather — Hakhel — at the end of the sabbatical year.

But is there a command to gather together on (every) Shabat or the Moadim?

Vayikra 23 calls such days Mikra Kodesh or Holy Convocations, but do these really imply that we should gather and keep these days together? Or are these just general statements in order that we should just proclaim these days as different as the other days and keep the holiness of these specific moments.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "gather". We daven together in Minyanim and have meals with our families and guests. Do you expect anything more, like a Chasidisher Tish?

Comment: @AlBerko my point is that the words mikra kodesh could be taken to mean ‘a declaration of sanctity’ refering to the holiness of a day or appointed time. While translated as ‘a holy convocation’ it refers to a group of people assembled for a special purpose; they are called together for a holy meeting, ‘a set-apart-gathering’. So the question is if we are really commanded to gather on these days and appointed times, or that these days and appointed times are only to be declared as holy days; i.e. are to be set apart from all other days.

Comment: Let's make something clear - we don't interpret the Tanach in terms of Halacha. We don't have the ability to infer anything Halachic straight from the writings unless it is stated by the Sages in the Talmud or elsewhere. Adopting your way may lead to serious misinterpreting of the TOrah.

Comment: @AlBerko you’re quite quick with judging, who says that I’m adopting my way? Who says it’s my way anyways? The only thing I ask is if the costum of gathering on Shabbat or during the Moadim is commanded or not, and if it isn’t then I would like to know how to interpret the words Mikra Kodesh. That’s all there is, just a question without sharing my view, interpretation or opinion. Although I did try to explain how one can define the terms Milra Kodesh in differt ways which influence the way one reads and interprets the meaning of those words.

Comment: ok, then, who's translating מקרא as "Convocations"? Onkelos says מערע - occasions.

Comment: @AlBerko Nachmanides explains it as such: see https://www.sefaria.org/Tur_HaAroch%2C_Leviticus.23.2.2?with=Tanakh&lang=bi besides translations like the OJPS translates it as a holy convocation, although the NJPS teanslates it as ‘sacred occasion like you did.

Comment: @AlBerko “Sacred convocations; as noted by Baruch Levine in the JPS commentary the phrase מקרא קדש is ambigious. Some render it as sacred occasions, yet the verbal root ק-ר-א connotes a call or invitation. Hence other translators prefer sacred assembly in that the Israelite public is invited on those special days to assemble for worship, learning and festivity.״ But anyway that’s not what I wanted to discuss. I wanted to discuss the part wether it is or isn’t a command to gather on days like Shabbat and the Moadim refered to as Mikra Kodesh in Vayikra 23.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to prove, a translator can not "translate it literally" as he pleases if there's no such tradition. Show me a traditional interpretation of מקרא as assembly, please to base your question on.

Comment: @AlBerko So Nachmanides was wrong to do so? Like Jewish commentators of today are wrong to do so? Doesn’t that prove that it is an excepted point of view?

Answer (score 0):

This was an answer I got from a Rabbi: 
In the days of old, there was an obligation for people to be oleh regel, to come to Yerushalayim to celebrate the holiday there. With no bes hamikdosh, there is no obligation specifically to 'come together' for the holiday. 
Since these days  holy days, one should make an effort not to spend  the day frivolously. The day should be spent studying Torah to the extent that one is able. For many people, that means gathering together to hear a shiur (Torah discourse). There was an ancient custom for people to gather together on the Shabas and Rosh Chodesh to hear words of Torah/Musar from the prophet. This is hinted to in Kings II, 4:23

Comment: What's the bottom line?

Comment: @AlBerko do I really need to explain myself again, the Rabi in question answered the question wether or not it is commanded to gather while on the same time he explains for what reason most of us do gather although it’s not specifically an obligation.